# Adding Line Break in Invoice PDF

Tags: invoice, pdf

This is the content of my store contact address:

```
text<br/>
text2<br/>
text3
```

I am getting this content in the Pdf/Abstract.php file, like:

```
$storeAddress = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/address');
```

and I displayed it like:

```
$page->drawText(
    $storeAddress, 350, $top - 54
);
```

For some reason, it didn't recognize the `<br/>` tag.

So I tried to replace the `<br/>` tag with `\n`, but I got the same result. Is there a way to add a line break in the PDF?  Thx !

Answer (score -2):

Try to wrap the part below the break in an <p>text</p>